# How to find binary compatibility for libraries built with gcc-4.9 vs gcc-6.2?

Tags: gcc, abi, toolchain

I have a vendor who supplies the SoC, associated BSP and some key middle-ware to us. Vendor uses gcc-4.9 to build all the delivered software.

The software delivered has two categories

- Source packages: we get all sources and build ourselves.
- Libraries and Binaries: we reuse what vendor delivers pre-built.

We plan to move to gcc-6.2, but vendor has no plans to move anytime soon.

So the questions arise:

1. For the pre-built binaries/libraries will there be ABI compatibility issues if we use gcc-6.2 and vendor delivers pre-builts with gcc-4.9. All the pre-built libs are shared objects.
2. Shall we expect compile time issues for the vendor's source packages (some packages have c as well as assembly), when we rebuild using gcc-6.2?

   - Target architecture is ARM.
   - We are putting together a Linux distribution.

I read about [abicheck](http://abicheck.sourceforge.net/), I am considering to run **abicheck** for all the vendor delivered pre-builts (built with 4.9) and objects I build with 6.2.

- Any pointers if this is the correct approach?
- Other suggestions are equally welcome.

Comment: **What is the architecture of SoC's CPU** and what is the OS, is it linux? GCC ABI has changes, and to run code compiled with newer GCC you usually should use newer libs, especially for C++. With linux you can use two sets of libs with some kind of chroot. And if newer libs can be compiled for your platform you may try to install newer libs and run older binaries.

Comment: It's arm architecture. Runs linux. The prebuilts are all written in C by the vendor.

Comment: If it's all C code you should be fine, the C ABIs doesn't change much. There are however old and new ABIs for ARM, and differing FPU choices. You're probably using the newer ABI and VFP floating-point math, but you need to make sure that both your old and new versions of GCC agree on these points. The abicheck isn't likely relevant to your problem, it doesn't diagnose problems caused by ABI differences. It's more of a correctness checker to make sure you're not doing a few things the program considers incorrect, like using a private symbol from a shared library or statically linking.

Comment: @RossRidge, thanks for your input on abicheck.